# Ошибка при выполнения SQL запроса (SQLite3, python)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def add_shop(ctx, num:int=None, amt:int=None, *, arg=None):
    if arg is None:
        await ctx.reply(f'**{ctx.author.mention}**, вы забыли указать название товара.')
    else:
        if num is None:
            ctx.reply(f'**{ctx.author.mention}**, вы забыли указать номер товара.')
        else:
            if amt is None:
                await ctx.reply(f'**{ctx.author.mention}**, вы забыли указать стоимость товара.')   
            else:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO shop VALUES ({}, {}, {})".format(num, arg, amt))
                connection.commit()
```

Сама таблица:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (
            item_id INT,
            item TEXT,
            cost BIGINT
        )""")
    connection.commit()
```

При выполнении выдаёт ошибку:

```
Command raised an exception: OperationalError: no such column: num.
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Исправьте ваш вопрос, чтобы текстовая информация была в вопросе текстом, а не картинками. Для этого есть специальные блоки вставки кода. Для этого нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1377756/edit) под самим вопросом. Я же вам поправил блоки кода. По данному примеру и надо оформлять

Comment: Текущий показанный вами код не может выдать такую ошибку, а ещё он уязвим для SQL-инъекции. Впрочем, в любом случае дубликат.

Comment: Вы всё-таки почитайте внимательно ответ по указанной вам ссылке. Тот способ, на который вы поменяли, тоже неудачный. Нужно использовать интерполяцию средствами самой библиотеки `sqlite`, а не питоновский `format`, тогда само всё правильно подставится.